# Accessing a dataweave object value via a variable

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to access a value in a Dataweave object via a variable whose value equals the key. So, if

```
var obj = {"a": 2}
var x = "a"
```

then I want something like `obj.x` to return `2`.

`obj.x`, `obj.(x)` don't work. I thought accessing the value via the key's index might work using something like `obj[(keysOf(obj) find "a")]`. But that didn't work either for reasons that I don't understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One more way other than that is already answered is like this :
obj."$(x)"

Comment: Please add alternative answers in the original question.